# Transparency issues with LWJGL

Tags: java, opengl, graphics, 3d, lwjgl

I am creating a CAD app in Java using LWJGL. Everything works fine, however, things drawn are kind of see-through (not transparent but you can see both the front and back, which makes it really confusing when moving shapes).

#### You can see what I mean in the following diagram:

[image]

I want the lines inside / in the back covered. Simply, what's in the front should cover everything that's in the back, instead of being see through. Any solutions/ tips?

#### EDIT:

Some code

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Window window = new Window();
        initDisplay();
        gameLoop();
        cleanUp();
    }

public static void initDisplay()
    {
        try {
            Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(800,600));
            Display.create();
        } catch (LWJGLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

public static void gameLoop()
    {
        cam = new Camera(70f,(float)(Display.getWidth()/Display.getHeight()),0.3f,1000f);
        x=0;
        while(!Display.isCloseRequested())
        {
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            glLoadIdentity();
            cam.useView();

                updateKeys();
            glPushMatrix();
            {
HERE's THE PART FOR DRAWING
}
glEnd();
glPopMatrix();
            Display.update();
```

Comment: try setting the display configuration   public static void setDisplayConfiguration(float gamma,
                           float brightness,
                           float contrast)

Comment: setting the display configuration didn't work :( it just turns the whole display white.

Comment: well it can be adjusted play around with it

Answer (score 1):

It would really help if you had a depth buffer for this sort of thing. Otherwise what is displayed is simply a matter of what you draw last.

Of course, if you used a depth buffer your lines (which I assume are a wireframe overlay) would not be visible because the default depth test is `GL_LESS` and they will generate (roughly) the same depth as the surface they are overlaid on. A depth test of `GL_LEQUAL` will go a long way toward solving that problem, but ultimately you generally need a small depth offset to prevent depth fighting when you try to overlay a wireframe like that.

*For future reference `HERE's THE PART FOR DRAWING` is not terribly useful in diagnosing problems.*

Comment: This solved it. Thank you. With "HERE'S THE PART FOR DRAWING" I meant that was just vertex information, but I'll take your advice into account next time :)